Scroll Into View
The problem is that i have 4 dashboard components in my Analytics page.. presently one appears after the another. but i would want it such that at any scroll position one full component table is fully in view or focus - there should not be any scenario where one half of one and half of other component comes in display/. if i scroll down or up from one component - immediately reach other component in full focus on display
<pre><code>
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import SharedDashboardComponent from '../components/shared/SharedDashboardComponent'
import AutoCompleteMonthlyAnalysis from '../components/shared/AutoCompleteMonthlyAnalysis'
import { useDashboardDataContext } from '../context/DashboardDataProvider'
import Variants from '../components/skeletons/ProductSkeleton'
import process_Rep_data from '../serviceFunctions/MonthlyAnalysis/rep_sales'
import process_doctor_data from '../serviceFunctions/MonthlyAnalysis/doctor_sales'
import chop_floating_point_values from '../serviceFunctions/MonthlyAnalysis/chop_float'
import SpanningTable from '../components/shared/monthlyanalysis/MonthlyAnalysisTable2'
import SpanningTable2 from '../components/shared/monthlyanalysis/TotalSaleProduct'
import SpanningTable3 from '../components/shared/monthlyanalysis/TotalSaleRep'
import SpanningTable4 from '../components/shared/monthlyanalysis/TotalSaleDoctor'


const monthNames = ["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]

const Analytics = () => {
const currentData = new Date();
const currentMonth = currentData.getMonth();
const currentYear = currentData.getFullYear();
console.log(currentMonth,currentYear)
  const [monthAndYear, setMonthAndYear] = useState({
    month: currentMonth,
    year: currentYear,
  });


  const {apiData,dataFetch} = useDashboardDataContext()
  const [data1,setData1] = useState(null);
  const [data2,setData2] = useState(null);
  const [data3,setData3] = useState(null);
  const [data4,setData4] = useState(null);
  // const [data,setData] = useState(undefined);
  const[repData,setRepData] = useState(null);
  const[doctorData,setDoctorData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // make the query for the current year and previous month
    const searchQuery = {year:currentYear,month:currentMonth+1}
    if(apiData==null){

      dataFetch(searchQuery)
    }
    // console.log("from analytics",apiData)
  },[])

  function agencySortByTotalAmount(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => b.totalAmount - a.totalAmount);
}

function productSortByTotalAmount(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => b.amount - a.amount);
}

function repSortByTotalAmount(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => b.sales - a.sales);
}

function doctorSortByTotalAmount(arr) {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => b.sales - a.sales);
}


// processing data for representatives section calling function from rep_sales.js

    useEffect(()=>{
    if(apiData!=null){
      const processedRepData = process_Rep_data(apiData[2]);
      console.log('rep',processedRepData)
      setRepData(processedRepData);

      const processedDoctorData = process_doctor_data(apiData[3]);
      console.log('doctor',processedDoctorData)
      setDoctorData(processedDoctorData);

      const d1 = chop_floating_point_values(apiData[0]);
      const sortedD1 =  agencySortByTotalAmount(d1);
      setData1(sortedD1);
      // console.log("hahahahahh",d1)
      const d2 = chop_floating_point_values(apiData[1]);
      const sortedD2 =  productSortByTotalAmount(d2);
      setData2(sortedD2);

      const d3 = chop_floating_point_values(processedRepData);
      const sortedD3 =  repSortByTotalAmount(d3);
      setData3(sortedD3);

      const d4 = chop_floating_point_values(processedDoctorData);
      const sortedD4 =  doctorSortByTotalAmount(d4);

      setData4(sortedD4);


      // console.log("from use effect apidata",apiData)
      // console.log("rep data processed",repData)
     
      // console.log("from use effect apidata",apiData)
      // console.log('doctorData processed',doctorData)
      }
    },[apiData])

    // const rep_data = process_Rep_data(apiData[2]);
    // console.log(rep_data)
    // console.log(barChartData.totalSalesInMonth.x,barChartData.totalSalesInMonth.y)
    const x = 'agencyName';
    const y= 'totalAmount';


  return (
    
    <div className='h-auto w-full p-4 bg-skin-screen-fill'>
      {apiData?

      <div className='bg-gradient-to-r from-[#49e6b7] to-white p-5 pb-7 flex flex-col gap-4 rounded-2xl  mt-3 bg-cover bg-center z-0' >
      <h1 className='text-4xl font-bold font-sans text-skin-base'>MONTHLY ANALYSIS</h1>  
      <AutoCompleteMonthlyAnalysis monthAndYear={monthAndYear} setMonthAndYear={setMonthAndYear} />
      {data1?<SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns.totalSalesInMonth} rows = {data1} title = {`TOTAL SALES IN ${monthNames[monthAndYear.month]} ${currentYear}`} x='agencyName' y='totalAmount' categoryGapRatio={0.8} ChildChart={SpanningTable} />:<Variants/> }
      {data2?<SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns.totalSalesOfProductInMonth} rows = {data2} title = {`TOTAL SALES OF PRODUCTS IN ${monthNames[monthAndYear.month]} ${currentYear}`} x='productName' y='amount' categoryGapRatio={0.4} ChildChart={SpanningTable2} />:<Variants/>}
      {data3?<SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns.totalSalesOfRepInMonth} rows = {repData} title = {`TOTAL SALES BY REPS IN ${monthNames[monthAndYear.month]} ${currentYear}`} x='repname' y='sales' categoryGapRatio={0.85} ChildChart={SpanningTable3} />
:<Variants /> }
      {data4?
      <SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns.totalSalesOfDoctorInMonth} rows = {doctorData} title = {`TOTAL SALES BY DOCTORS IN ${monthNames[monthAndYear.month]} ${currentYear}`} x='doctor_name' y='sales' categoryGapRatio={0.35} ChildChart={SpanningTable4} />:
      <Variants />}
       {/* {data1?<SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns2.totalSalesInMonth} rows = {data1} title = "TOTAL SALES IN A MONTH" x='agencyName' y='totalAmount' />:<Variants/> }
      {data2?<SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns2.totalSalesOfProductInMonth} rows = {data2} title = "TOTAL SALES OF PRODUCTS IN A MONTH" x='productName' y='amount' />:<Variants/>}
      {data3?<SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns2.totalSalesOfRepInMonth} rows = {repData} title = "TOTAL SALES OF REPS IN A MONTH" x='repname' y='sales' />
:<Variants /> }
      {data4?
      <SharedDashboardComponent columns={allTableColumns2.totalSalesOfDoctorInMonth} rows = {doctorData} title = "TOTAL SALES OF DOCTOR IN A MONTH" x='doctor_name' y='sales' />:
      <Variants />} */}


      </div>

:<Variants />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Analytics


// const barChartData = {
//   totalSalesInMonth:{x:'agencyName',y:'totalAmount'},
// }
// xTotalSalesInMonth = 'agencyName';
// yTotalSalesInMonth = 'totalAmount';



const allTableColumns = {totalSalesInMonth:[
  { field: 'agencyName', headerName: 'STOCKIST', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted',align:'center',headerAlign:'center' },
  { field: 'totalAmount', headerName: 'TOTAL SALES', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],
totalSalesOfProductInMonth:[
  { field: 'productName', headerName: 'PRODUCT', width: 200,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { field: 'amount', headerName: 'TOTAL SALES', width: 150,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted'},
  { field: 'quantity', headerName: 'TOTAL QUANTITY', width: 190,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],
totalSalesOfRepInMonth:[
  { field: 'repname', headerName: 'REPRESENTATIVE', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { field: 'sales', headerName: 'TOTAL SALES', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],
totalSalesOfDoctorInMonth:[
  { field: 'doctor_name', headerName: 'DOCTOR', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { field: 'sales', headerName: 'TOTAL SALES', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],};


//===============================================================================================================================================

const allTableColumns2 = {totalSalesInMonth:[ 
  { id: 'agencyName', label: 'Agency', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { id: 'totalAmount', label: 'Total Sales', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],
totalSalesOfProductInMonth:[
  { id: 'productName', label: 'Product', width: 200,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { id: 'amount', label: 'Total Sales', width: 150,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted'},
  { id: 'quantity', label: 'Total Quantity', width: 190,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],
totalSalesOfRepInMonth:[
  { id: 'repname', label: 'Representative', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { id: 'sales', label: 'Total Sales', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],
totalSalesOfDoctorInMonth:[
  { id: 'doctor_name', label: 'Doctor', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
  { id: 'sales', label: 'Total Sales', width: 270,headerClassName:'text-lg text-bold font-sans font-bold bg-skin-fill text-skin-inverted' },
 
],};



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please its urgent - something related to focus function - or scrollable
